# How to access CSS on img tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need some help with CSS. I am trying to create a tree with lots of `<ul>` and `<li>` tags. The problem is that I have many `<li>` tags with a particular class, and inside that list I have an `<img>` tag.

How can I access that `<img>` tag and put different background image? I am confused how to point my `<img>` tag with the class of the `<li>` and then set a background-image

Note: CSS3 is not allowed

```
<ul>
  <li class="leaf"><img></li>
  <li class="leafhidden"><img></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: for your <img> to work, it needs at least a src attribute (in FireFox)

Comment: If you are using background images (as you state) you would  **not** put them in the HTML at all. You would apply the bg image property to the `li`. JSFiddle needed I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can differentiate the `<img>` tags via:

```
li.leaf > img {
    background: url("/images/leaf_bg.png");
} 
li.leafhidden > img {
    background: url("/images/leaf_hidden_bg.png");
}
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense. `img` does not have `background` style.

Comment: Agreed...answer makes no sense.

Comment: @dfsq: according to the specs that might be true. please show me one browser that 100% conforms to all specs. (pick one, i don't care if HTML 3.2, 4.0, 5.0, XHTML 1.0, CSS 1.2, 2.0, 3.0 ...) Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qq3xh/ I am too lazy to test in another browser. tried firefox, works.